# Get the path of the importing script from within a module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to get the path of a script that imported a module from within that module?

The script module I'm writing is meant to load settings from files relative to the importing script. I plan on reusing the module for a number of projects, so I would prefer if the module could make no assumptions about where its being imported from.

This is a nice to have, it would be great the module could be as implicit as possible. If all else fails though, I can just have the caller pass in its location.

Unfortunately everything I've attempted so far returns the path to the module (not what imported it). Here's a simple demonstration:

---

**Test-RelativeModule.ps1**, *Stored at:* c:\test\

```bash
import-module "$PSScriptRoot\mod\Test.psm1"
```

**Test.psm1**, *Stored at:* c:\test\mod\

```bash
# returns 'c:\test\mod'
write-host "`$PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot"

# returns 'c:\test\mod'
# The value of $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path is 'c:\test\mod\Test.psm1'
write-host "Split Invoation: $(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)"

# returns whatever path the console is currently residing
write-host "Resolve Path: $((resolve-path '.\').path)"

# what I'm looking for is something to return 'c:\test' from within the module
# without making any assumptions about the folder structure
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Write-Host "My invoker's PSScriptRoot: $($MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot)"
```

Comment: *So close*! `Split-Path` isn't needed. Just: `Write-Host "Invoker: $($MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot)"` -- Edit and I'll accept. Thanks!